# VB.NET Pocket PC Database connection

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have created a database using SQlServer CE with the name of db.sdf using the following code.

```
Dim connStr As String = "Data Source =\temp\emp.sdf;"
Try
            'creating database
            Dim engine As SqlCeEngine
            engine = New SqlCeEngine(connStr)
            engine.CreateDatabase()
            engine.Dispose()

            'creating table
            Dim cn As New SqlCeConnection(connStr)
            Dim sql As String
            sql = "CREATE TABLE login "
            sql &= "("
            sql &= "    username   nvarchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,"
            sql &= "    password   nvarchar(20)"
            sql &= ")"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCeCommand(sql, cn)
            cmd.Connection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Connection.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
            cn.Dispose()

            MessageBox.Show("Succesfully created")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

But i dont know where it keeps this emp.sdf file and how to view this. I have just started working on VB.NET Pocket PC application today and i am very confuse because my VB.NET connection code is not working as well with Pocket PC application so please help me how to solve this problem. Please any tutorial which can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim cnn As SqlConnection

        connetionString = "Data Source=database server name;Initial Catalog=database name"
        cnn = New SqlConnection(connection string)
        Try
            cnn.Open()

            MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
            cnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")


        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You have provided the database name in your connect string when you created the database...

```
Dim connStr As String = "Data Source =\temp\emp.sdf;"
```

... so you should find a \temp folder under \My Device that has the emp.sdf file in it.